# Can this sum of squares of digits of a number puzzle's solution be optimized further?

Tags: java, math, optimization, time-complexity, puzzle

The below code calculates a value which is obtained as sum of square of each digits in `str`. This sum is again calculate `m` times.

```
Example: m = 2, str="123"
At m=1 (1^2)+(2^2)+(3^2) = 1+4+9 = 14
At m=2 (1^2)+(4^2) = 1+16 = 17
```

So 17 should be the final answer for this input. For large inputs or when run against 1000 of test case like above, this code is giving time limit exceeded errors. Can this code further optimized?

```
Test case will be less than 1001
1 <= str.length(), m <= 10^9

         public static void puzzle(int m,String str) {
            int ans = 0;
            while (m > 0) {
                ans=0;
                m--;
                int j = 0;
                while (j < str.length()) {
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(str.charAt(j) + "");
                    ans +=  val* val;
                    j++;
                }
                str = String.valueOf(ans);
            }
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
```

I have tried my level best and could come up with above iterative solution. Could not improve even with a recursive solution.

**Recursive Code:**

```
public static int solve(int m, String n){
        if(m < 1)
            return Integer.parseInt(n);
        int idx = 0;
        int res = 0;
        while(idx< n.length()){
            int val = Integer.parseInt(n.charAt(idx) + "");
            res += val*val;
            idx++;
        }
        return solve(m-1,String.valueOf(res));
    }
```

Comment: What is the maximum number initially? Are you assured that the result will hold in a 32 bit `int` ? Because there is much room for technical optimization in this case, and if not, then your solution would be wrong. My suspicion comes from your comment `M <= 10^9`... What does that mean??

Comment: updated the code. m <= 10^9 means that m can hold up to 10^9 values.
Can you list your technical optimizations?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the operation using strings. Stay with integers.

Since you're just adding the square of digits, you can do it starting with the last digit, so a loop doing modulus and division by 10, until zero, will do the trick.

```
public static int puzzle(int m, String str) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (; value != 0; value /= 10) {
            int digit = value % 10;
            sum += digit * digit;
        }
        value = sum;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me why you are suggesting not to use string operations?

Comment: Unnecessary overhead. How do you think a number is converted to a string? You wanted optimization, this is it. Your code is converting to String (new object), then iterating the chars, doing a `char + ""` which means `new StringBuilder().append(char).append("").toString()` (2 new objects per iteration), then `parseInt()`. High overhead. If you at least had done a simple `char - '0'` it might be bearable, but that???